# Wordpress update post frequently

Tags: wordpress

I am updating my posts recently more than 3 times. I read while ago that it's bad for SEO and google. Because google will think I am spamming the posts or something, there was a plugin to prevent that but I forgot the name.

Please can you help me?

What the plugin does: when you post something it tells google once. So if I update the post 10 times it won't send notifications to google about that. Only once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of this plugin [cbnet Ping Optimizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cbnet-ping-optimizer/) ?

According to the plugin description, the plugin is not needed anymore:

> Because this Plugin's functionality is no longer needed. In fact, this Plugin's functionality may never have been needed in the first place. But regardless of that, it certainly isn't needed now.